# StructureMap: "No default instance of plugin defined" - even though it is

Tags: structuremap

I've been using StructureMap for about 6 months now; you would think it would start getting easier.  It doesn't seem to.

Here's the first line of my registry:

```
            For<IDbConnection>()
            .Singleton()
            .Use<SqlConnection>()
            .Ctor<string>(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UnifiedConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

It compiles and runs.  But when I try to use that Interface, like this:

```
            return MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(((DbConnection)ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDbConnection>()).ConnectionString);
```

I get

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.Data.IDbConnection, System.Data,
 Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Now I may be missing something (okay, I obviously am), but I don't know how much more plain I can be about defining the default instance for IDbConnection.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Per Joshua's request, I'm adding full code for a minimal case.

I've tried to create a console app that reproduces the error.  It ends up not reproducing it, but giving a different SM exception, which I also don't understand.  But maybe when I understand that one, I'll have a clue as to what's going on in the production app.

First, my console app:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.Print("Connection String: {0}", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UnifiedConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        (new Bootstrapper()).BootstrapStructureMap();

    }
```

Then, my Bootstrapper module, lifted from the production app:

```
    public class Bootstrapper : IBootstrapper
{
    public  void BootstrapStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>

                x.Scan(s =>
                {
                    s.WithDefaultConventions();
                    s.TheCallingAssembly();
                    s.LookForRegistries();
                }
                    )
        );
        Debug.Print(ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave());
        try
        {
            ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
        catch (StructureMapConfigurationException ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }
        InitAutoMapper();
    }
```

And finally, the DependencyRegistry, lifted from the production app, but with everything beyond the first statement commented out.

```
    public class DependencyRegistry : Registry
{
    public DependencyRegistry()
    {     
        For<IDbConnection>()
            .Singleton()
            .Use<SqlConnection>()
            .Ctor<string>(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UnifiedConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        //For<...
    }
}
```

Now what I get when I run this is that it's making it through "WhatDoIHave()", but it's throwing an SM 205 exception on the AssertConfigurationIsValid(). The error (apparently) occurs trying to instantiate SqlConnection, saying "Missing requested Instance property \"connectionString\" for InstanceKey ".

Here's the text of the message:

### StructureMap.Exceptions.StructureMapConfigurationException:

Build Error on Instance 'a54d3ca1-33b5-4100-82d4-13e458f57a3f' (Configured Instance of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    for PluginType System.Data.IDbConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  205
Missing requested Instance property "connectionString" for InstanceKey "a54d3ca1-33b5-4100-82d4-13e458f57a3f"
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.<.ctor>b__0(String key)
   at StructureMap.Util.Cache`2.get_Item(KEY key)
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get(String propertyName, Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get[T](String propertyName, BuildSession session)
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Arguments.Get[T](String propertyName)
   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , IArguments )
   at StructureMap.Construction.BuilderCompiler.FuncCompiler`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IArguments args)

... (Hopefully nothing relevant deleted for space)...

StructureMap Failures:  1 Build/Configuration Failures and 0 Validation Errors

at StructureMap.Container.AssertConfigurationIsValid()
   at StructureMap.ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid()
   at ConsoleIoCTest.Bootstrapper.BootstrapStructureMap() in U:\dave\VS2008Projects\FMSWeb\FMSWeb\ConsoleIoCTest\Bootstrapper.cs:line 29

Got all that?  Neither do I.  Why is it saying it's missing the constructor key "connectionString" when I'm passing it as a .ctor argument?

Thanks, and sorry for taking up all that space.

Comment: I'm guessing there is something you aren't showing us. Please post the full code of a unit test (or simple console app) with the bare minimum that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: Joshua,
Thanks for your response. 
Since this is the DI for the live database, which, of course, is not used in the unit testing (hey, that's 90% of the rationale for DI in my opinion), I don't have a unit test that shows it.  I'm using a different registry in test mode, and also, this dependency is only used in the MS SQL database, not in the SQLite DB that I use for testing.
But I'll see if I can come up with a minimal case.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that you're missing the "Is part" of the Ctor dependency instruction.

```
For<IDbConnection>()
  .Singleton()
  .Use<SqlConnection>()
  .Ctor<string>().Is(theConnectionString);
```

Comment: +1 I had a similar problem and wasn't providing the necessary constructor argument.